# What's the point of NOT-operator logic?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, not-operator

What's the point of not (!) logic? It seems that you can do everything not can do with all the other logical operators. Is there something that not can do that I am missing?

Comment: How can you test if your glass is not full without it? ;-)

Comment: Take a look here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functionally_complete

Answer (score 2):

You won't deny that the NOT-operator is very *convenient* in a programming language even if the other operators and built-in constants available in that
language render it strictly redundant. *Convenience* is an adequate justification - in fact it is *the* justification - for almost all features of all general
programming languages. If we didn't care about convenience - which in programming, means *productivity* - we could write all programs with a set of 
Turing-complete op-codes far smaller even than any assembly language.

The degree of inconvenience you would face in doing without the NOT-operator depends on the programming language you are considering and specifically
on the other operators and built-in-constants that the language provides and their semantics.

In C, for example, the equality operator `==` exists but there are no built-in constants representing truth and falsity: any integral value all of whose bits are 0 behaves as falsity in boolean operations and all other integral values behave as truth. `!cond` evaluates to 0 if `cond` evaluates non-zero and otherwise evaluates to 1. Thus
to say that `cond` is not true without coding `!cond` you have to code `cond == 0`, taking at least 2 keystrokes more.

Like C, C++ has equality and inequality operators but unlike C it represents the boolean truth valiues by the built-in constants `true` and `false`. Thus
to say that `cond` is not true in C++ without coding `!cond` you must code either `cond != true` or `cond == false`, taking at least 5 keystrokes more.

And the cost of doing without the NOT-operator can potentially compound beyond minor inconvenience. Which of the following can you understand first?:

```
!(p && !q) == (!p || q)
```

or:

```
(((p && (q == 0)) == 0) == ((p == 0) || q)
```

Comment: WRT "...we could write all programs with a set of Turing-complete op-codes far smaller even than any assembly language.": [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement all logical operators solely with the NAND operator. The NOT operator is for convenience, just like all the others are. In fact, computer systems are implemented solely with either the NAND or the NOR operator. All other operators are abstractions put in place for convenience.

It *is* convenient, however. Since you mention the "!" operator, I assume you mean boolean operators in  general programming languages. Then the not operator is very convenient. Imagine you wanted to express something like "print all names except 'Bob'". You could do that with the != operator, which is a further short-form of !(expression1 == expression2):

```
if( !(name == 'Bob') ) {
    print name
}
```